VS Code WSL stuck on "Opening Remote..."
I recently started having this issue, that after I open up a (specific) repository for the second time, vs code gets stuck in loading mode, and the status bar shows "Opening Remote..." message at the remote indicator.
This happens starting from the second time of me opening that repo as workspace, it only applies to that repository at that location (meaning, resetting or deleting the repository and cloning it again at the same path doesn't work, but cloning it and using a different path works, maybe cache related(?)),
also opening the workspace on the parent folder or one of the child folders works okay as well, only that specific repository and not other.
I couldn't find anything worth mentioning in all of the output tabs, and no tab of WSL log or anything like that was available
The repository in question is quite ironically VS code own repository, if that might help slimming down the options for the cause
I'm using Windows 11 Pro 23H2
WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04.4
Visual Studio Code v1.89.1
Would love help and/or directions to explore!
